# How to store array within a for loop using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have a complete `j query` that loop through a list of names stored in an array and random select three names to be winner. i want if selected name, store in array and then push to div.

js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

js -->

```
var members = [
    { 'Member_ID': 0, 'Member_Name': "Malon Namak" },
    { 'Member_ID': 1, 'Member_Name': "Tom Joseph" },
    { 'Member_ID': 2, 'Member_Name': "Noah Iaruel" },
    { 'Member_ID': 3, 'Member_Name': "Rodricco Simil" },
    { 'Member_ID': 4, 'Member_Name': "Nax Kev" },
    { 'Member_ID': 6, 'Member_Name': "Raphaela Seru" },

];

var $display = $("#display");
var $draw = $("#draw");
var count = 1;
var $random = $("#random");
var $head = $("#head");
var $slider_1 = ("#slider_1");
var $slider_2 = ("#slider_2");
var $slider_3 = ("#slider_3");
var els =[];
$('#random').click(function(){
    $('#random').attr("value", + (count++) + "/3" );

    var total = members.length,
        selected = Math.floor( Math.random() * total ),
        i = 0;

    console.log( "selected", selected );
    for (i=0; i<total; i++) {

        console.log( "for", i );
                setTimeout((function(i){
            return function(){

                console.log( "timeout", i );
                $display.text( members[i].Member_Name.toUpperCase() );
                if( i === selected ) {
                    $head.text("Winning!!");
                    $head.animate( {"font-size": "20px"}, "slow");
                    $display.animate( {"font-size": "40px"}, "slow");


                }
            };
        }(i)), i*250);





        if( i === selected ) {


        break;
        }
    }

    if (count == 4){
        $('#random').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#random').attr("value", "0");

        $draw.text("You have reach the limit");


    };

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Draw</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="display" name="display">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="random" value="Draw" />
    <div id="total" name="total">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="draw" >
    </div>
<div id="cover">
    <div id="slider_1"><p class="content"></p></div>
    <div id="slider_2"><p class="content"></p></div>
    <div id="slider_3"><p class="content"></p></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
<br />
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Creating an array in JavaScript and adding an element to it are well documented concepts with lots of examples online.  What isn't working?

Comment: @David i want to push winner three names to div #cover

Comment: So you're asking how to add content to an element from jQuery?  `.text()`, `.html()`, `.append()`, etc.

Comment: yes from from selected list.

Comment: Nobody here is going to write all of your code for you.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  In the question you're asking how to use arrays in JavaScript, which is covered by JavaScript tutorials.  In the comments you're asking how to write content to HTML elements with jQuery, which is covered by jQuery tutorials.  What *specifically* are you actually asking and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply need to take your winning names and use text() to insert into the appropriate div. would be easier if the three winning names were classes instead of id's but not to worry.

The winning names are also pushed into the `els` array, which is assumed to be the one you want to keep the names in.

Using your code to make a snippet further notes are in the comments.

```js
var members = [{
    'Member_ID': 0,
    'Member_Name': "Malon Namak"
  }, {
    'Member_ID': 1,
    'Member_Name': "Tom Joseph"
  }, {
    'Member_ID': 2,
    'Member_Name': "Noah Iaruel"
  }, {
    'Member_ID': 3,
    'Member_Name': "Rodricco Simil"
  }, {
    'Member_ID': 4,
    'Member_Name': "Nax Kev"
  }, {
    'Member_ID': 6,
    'Member_Name': "Raphaela Seru"
  },

];

var $display = $("#display");
var $draw = $("#draw");
var count = 1;
var $random = $("#random");
var $head = $("#head");
var $slider_1 = ("#slider_1");
var $slider_2 = ("#slider_2");
var $slider_3 = ("#slider_3");
var els = [];
var inc = 1; // winning div counter
$('#random').click(function() {
  $('#random').attr("value", +(count++) + "/3");

  var total = members.length,
    selected = Math.floor(Math.random() * total),
    i = 0;

  console.log("selected", selected);
  for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {

    console.log("for", i);
    setTimeout((function(i) {
      return function() {

        console.log("timeout", i);
        $display.text(members[i].Member_Name.toUpperCase());
        if (i === selected) {
          $head.text("Winning!!");
          $head.animate({
            "font-size": "20px"
          }, "slow");
          $display.animate({
            "font-size": "40px"
          }, "slow");
          var wins = $display.text(); // get the winners name
          $('#slider_' + inc).find('.content').text(wins); // insert into suitable div
          els.push(wins);
          inc++; // move onto the next div
        }
      };
    }(i)), i * 250);

    if (i === selected) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (count > 3) {
    $('#random').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#random').attr("value", "0");

    $draw.text("You have reach the limit");


  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<div id="head">
</div>
<div id="display" name="display">
</div>
<input type="button" id="random" value="Draw" />
<div id="total" name="total">
</div>
<br />
<div id="draw">
</div>
<div id="cover">
  <div id="slider_1">
    <p class="content"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="slider_2">
    <p class="content"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="slider_3">
    <p class="content"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer appreciated your help